# How to disconnect function from QAction?

Tags: python, qt4, qgis, qaction

I am developing a plugin for the GIS software, QGIS. I have a [QAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html) icon which, when checked, connects layers in a group to a function whenever their visibility is toggled. Then when it is unchecked, it is supposed to disconnect these functions but instead I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Me/.qgis2/python/plugins\Example\Example.py", line 248, in run
    layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_one)            
TypeError: 'function' object is not connected
```

---

This is an example code:

```
def run(self, checked):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup('Group')

    def print_one():
        print 'one'

    if checked == True:            
        for layers in group.children():
            layers.visibilityChanged.connect(print_one)            
    else:
        for layers in group.children():
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_one)
```

---

Why is the signal not being disconnected?

I could just use `layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect()` but this disconnects all signals to it so is not in my interest.

Comment: Possible duplicated http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227719/how-to-disconnect-a-signal-when-untoggling-plugin-icon

Comment: @FranciscoRaga - Although the answer in the post you linked to works, this new question is asking ***why*** can it be connected in the `if` statement but cannot be disconnected in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 2):

For what I understood in PyQt manual, you should try this way :

```
layers.disconnect(print_one)
```

But I'm not sure and sadly I don't have time to try it...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this produces an error: `TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.disconnect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'function'
  QObject.disconnect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable): argument 1 has unexpected type 'function'`

Comment: My bad, I did not understand what you wanted to do.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I only found a workaround so the question is still open :)

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) (emphasis mine):

> **disconnect([slot])**
>
> Disconnect one or more slots from a signal. **An exception will be raised if the slot is not connected to the signal** or if the signal has no connections at all.

Thus, you are receiving an exception because the signal is not connected to the slot when you are trying to disconnect it.

As a workaround:

```
if checked == True:            
    for layers in group.children():
        layers.visibilityChanged.connect(print_one)            
else:
    for layers in group.children():
        try:
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_one) 
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is exactly what I tried before. Obviously no errors appear because it is being passed but it still does not disconnect the slot for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Guess I found an alternative method which is to include an `if` statement to check if the QAction icon is checked or not and place this inside the `print_one()` function:

```
def run(self):
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup('Group')

    def print_one():
        if self.plugin_icon.isChecked():
            print 'one'
        else:
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_one)             

    for layers in group.children():
        layers.visibilityChanged.connect(print_one)
```

Still curious as to why I couldn't disconnect it using the method shown in the question but in the meantime, this works.